# How to display one of the simple product price in configurable product price?

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

How to display one of the simple product price in configurable product price

Comment: instead of configurable product price do you want to show simple product price ??

Comment: Yes,I want to display one of the simple product price

Comment: Ok should I suggest you an extension or custom development code ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this ready extension for your requirement

https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple

But this extension has one problem in magento1.9 with reindexing, but fortunately people already found solution for that you can use

you can follow this blog

http://teition.com/price-indexer-will-not-re-index-in-magento/

OR

Follow this thread https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple/issues/282

for solution and you wonder that this will work for you.

Comment: I have integrated extension in my localhost.Reindexing issues  is coming.

Comment: @SumaJ  Follow this tutorial http://teition.com/price-indexer-will-not-re-index-in-magento/

Comment: In code everything has been changed already.

Comment: download updated configurable.php file from this thread https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple/issues/282

Comment: I have replace the file Still facing the same problem. I have installed magento 1.9.2.2

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala Configurable products by default in magento right, how to solve 0 if choose options?